# X86 architecture - Set Vector size with unsigned long long

Tags: c++, vector, visual-c++, x86, unsigned-long-long-int

When I am trying to set vector size with unsigned long long in x86 architecture, I am seeing below error:

```
unsigned long long sz;
vec.resize(sz);
```

> error C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'unsigned __int64' to 'const
> unsigned int', possible loss of data

Why is this error? what is the behavior of unsigned long long in x86 architecture? How to set vector size with unsigned long long value in x86 architecture?

Comment: *Why is this error?* -- [Read the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize).  Where is `unsigned long long` specified as being the type to use?

Comment: Sizes are size_t, not unsigned long long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `size_t sz` like a normal person, that's the arg type  `std::vector::resize(size_t)` expects, so using the same type will mean there's no implicit conversion and thus no narrowing.

`unsigned long long` is a 64-bit type, but `size_t` is only 32-bit, in 32-bit code.

You can't have a `std::vector` larger than `SIZE_MAX`, so it's pointless to use a wider integer type.  That's all MSVC is complaining about.  It's not an error if you never actually have a huge value in `sz`, but you've apparently set MSVC to be really pedantic and treat warnings as errors.

This implicit conversion is unnecessary in the first place; avoid it by using a matching type.

Comment: MSVC isn't complaining about the pointlessness of using a wider integer type. It's warning you about implicit integer conversions, which, in my opinion, are the biggest misfeature of the C++ language. See [the documentation for C4244](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-levels-3-and-4-c4244). This is a warning at -W3 and -W4. You're right that the asker clearly has -Werror set, but I think you are a bit too dismissive of the utility of this warning, especially in the general case.

Comment: @CodyGray: Thanks, fixed. That's what I meant (that the implicit conversion was pointless, not the warning), but of course if someone knew C++ well enough to understand my point from what I initially wrote, they wouldn't have needed to ask the question.  My answer was low-effort because it was initially going to be a comment.  I was hoping for a more interesting question based on the title, but vector was `std::vector` not a SIMD vector, and there was nothing x86-specific, just a platform with 32-bit `size_t`. :/

Comment: Haha, yeah, I could sense the frustration from the very first sentence. I also chuckled.